# IOS Application upload on AppStore

Tags: ios, macos, app-store

I am building a game in Unity3d for Android and IOS. Will I need a MAC or Hackintosh to upload the game to AppStore or can it be done using Windows

Can you guys let me the procedure to upload games to AppStore

Comment: On Google, just type "procedure to upload games to AppStore", your answer is just there.

Answer (score -1):

I think your answer should be a little more precise. It doesn't make much sense to me. From what I understand, you want to know if you can upload a game to the appStore. Developing iOS apps require you to have an apple computer and are written in either swift or objective-c. So yes you will need a mac to develop AND upload an app to the appStore.

Comment: I am using Unity to make my cross platform game in Windows. So I don't need a Mac to make the game. My precise question is that Will I need a Mac to upload my game to Appstore